# Initialize this to a final variable in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to initialize a final variable in a class to this.

```
Class C{
  final int variable1 = 0; //dynamically generated value
  final int variable2;

  C(): this.variable2 = this.variable1 + 1; //variable2 need access to "this" to initialize

}
```

Comment: As a constructor initializer, that's not feasible

Comment: If variable1 is 0 then variable2 is also 0, isn’t it?

Comment: @RémiRousselet is there any way to something similar where I can access "this" to initialize a final variable of a class.

Comment: No you cannot use `this` to initialise variables

Comment: @RémiRousselet so than is there any way to keep the variable unchangeable and able to initialize with ```this```, any workaround since in my program I really need to initialize my variable with ```this```, and it should be unchangeable for rest of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a private constructor with a public factory constructor.

```
class C {
  final int variable1;
  final int variable2;

  C._(this.variable1, this.variable2);

  factory C() {
    var v1 = Random().nextInt(10);
    return C._(v1, v1 + 1);
  }

  @override
  String toString() => 'Instance of C $variable1 $variable2';
}
```

Comment: I already thought of that actually, I need access to ```this```  for ```variable2``` too

Answer (score 1):

With regard to the API of your class, a `final` member variable is not really any different from providing a getter.  Since you want `variable2` to never be reassigned and to be based on `variable1`, it could exist solely as a getter:

```dart
class C {
  final int variable1 = 0;
  int get variable2 => variable1 + 1;

  ...
}
```

If you don't want to repeat the computation every time `variable2` is accessed, you could use a private member variable with a public getter:

```dart
class C {
  final int variable1 = 0;

  int get variable2 => _variable2;
  int _variable2;

  C() {
    _variable2 = variable1 + 1;
  }
}
```